# How to use postscripts from metapost as images in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, postscript, metapost

I produce two postscript files runing metapost on the file `example.mp` containing:

```
beginfig(1);
u=1cm;
draw (2u,2u)--(0,0)--(0,3u)--(3u,0)--(0,0);
pickup pencircle scaled 4pt;
for i=0 upto 2:
for j=0 upto 2: drawdot (i*u,j*u); endfor
endfor
endfig;

beginfig(2);
z0 = (0,0); z1 = (60,40);
z2 = (40,90); z3 = (10,70);
z4 = (30,50);
draw z0..z1..z2..z3..z4
endfig;

end
```

`example.1` content is:

```
%!PS
%%BoundingBox: -2 -2 86 86 
%%HiResBoundingBox: -1.99252 -1.99252 85.28935 85.28935 
%%Creator: MetaPost 2.00
%%CreationDate: 2023.07.15:2110
%%Pages: 1
%%BeginProlog
%%EndProlog
%%Page: 1 1
 0 0 0 setrgbcolor 0 0.5 dtransform truncate idtransform setlinewidth pop
 [] 0 setdash 1 setlinecap 1 setlinejoin 10 setmiterlimit
newpath 56.6929 56.6929 moveto
0 0 lineto
0 85.03935 lineto
85.03935 0 lineto
0 0 lineto stroke
 0 3.98505 dtransform truncate idtransform setlinewidth pop
newpath 0 0 moveto 0 0 rlineto stroke
newpath 0 28.34645 moveto 0 0 rlineto stroke
newpath 0 56.6929 moveto 0 0 rlineto stroke
newpath 28.34645 0 moveto 0 0 rlineto stroke
newpath 28.34645 28.34645 moveto 0 0 rlineto stroke
newpath 28.34645 56.6929 moveto 0 0 rlineto stroke
newpath 56.6929 0 moveto 0 0 rlineto stroke
newpath 56.6929 28.34645 moveto 0 0 rlineto stroke
newpath 56.6929 56.6929 moveto 0 0 rlineto stroke
showpage
%%EOF
```

I want to use the results, `example.1` and `example.2` as node images in a graph.

I run `dot -Tps example.dot -o example.ps`.

`example.dot`'s content is:

```
strict graph {
    {
        node [shape=none, label=""];
        1 [image="example.1"];
        2 [image="example.2"];
    }
    1 -- 2;
}
```

I get warning messages:

```
Warning: "example.1" was not found as a file or as a shape library member
Warning: No or improper image="example.1" for node "1"
Warning: "example.2" was not found as a file or as a shape library member
Warning: No or improper image="example.2" for node "2"
```

And the nodes' images are missing in `example.ps`.

How can I do to manage to see them in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphviz seems to not like the format of your 2 Postscript files (even though seemingly quite legal).
Use Ghostscript to "fix" these files `ps2ps example.1 Example.1` or some such, fix the naming of the files, and try again.  Worked for me.

Comment: Probably it doesn't like the fact that the files begin "%!PS". That's perfectly valid, and the correct de facto standard for a PostScript program, but it isn't correct for an EPS file (despite the other comments) and it doesn't declare itself to be DSC- compliant. I suspect Graphviz wants it to be an EPS.

Comment: I actually used `eps2eps`. The produced files are 20 times bigger than the original ones, but at least, they work! Thanks!

Comment: You are probably rendering to an image then, so the quality will be compromised. Perhaps you are using an old version of Ghostscript ?